# Perl: Constructing an array of objects

Tags: perl, oop, swig

Partially related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002046) but different, as this is about constructor calls...

I would like to create an array of a fixed number of objects.

I could do this:

```
my @objects;
push( @objects, new MyPackage::MyObject() );
push( @objects, new MyPackage::MyObject() );
push( @objects, new MyPackage::MyObject() );
# ...
```

That's several kinds of ugly. Making it a loop is only marginally better.

Isn't there a way to create an array of (constructor-initialized) objects in Perl?

**Afterthought question:**

These "objects" I want to create are actually SWIG-generated wrappers for C structs, i.e. data structures without "behaviour" (other than the SWIG-generated `get` and `set` functions). I just want to pass the array as a parameter to the C function, which will fill the structures for me; do I *need* to call constructors at all, or is there a shortcut to having the `get` functions for reading the struct contents afterwards? (Yes, I am *awfully* new to OOPerl...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There Is More Than One Concise Way To Do It:

```
my @objects = map { new MyPackage::MyObject() } 1..$N;

my @objects = ();
push @objects, new MyPackage::MyObject() for 1..$N;
```

Comment: I just love that first answer, would never have thought of that.

Comment: I voted up the answer, because I would use `map` too, but boo on the indirect object syntax `MyPackage::MyObject0->new()` is much much much better, the other way brings many ambiguities.

Comment: In fact, they are talking about removing indirect object syntax in a future version http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2011/09/a-look-at-the-future-of-perl-5.php frame 271. Also see [`perldoc perlobj`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Indirect-Object-Syntax)

Comment: The first solution is pure beauty, and exactly what I hoped to find. @Joel Berger: Thanks for the hint, I'd never have thought that the so familiar-looking `new ...` syntax had footholes in Perl.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the loop and repeating the same statement by supplying multiple arguments to `push`:

```
push(@objects, 
  new MyPackage::MyObject(), 
  new MyPackage::MyObject(), 
  new MyPackage::MyObject());
```

This is possible because the prototype of `push` is `push ARRAY,LIST`.

Or you can do it in a more straightforward way with an array composer (preferable):

```
my @objects = (
  new MyPackage::MyObject(), 
  new MyPackage::MyObject(), 
  new MyPackage::MyObject(),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can say

```
@objects = (new MyPackage::MyObject(), new MyPackage::MyObject(), new MyPackage::MyObject());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a list of objects and assign it to your array:

```
my @objects= (
  new MyPackage::MyObject(),
  new MyPackage::MyObject(),
  new MyPackage::MyObject(), 
  # ...
);
```